# Expo push notifications with managed workflow doesn't work

Tags: react-native, push-notification, notifications, expo, apple-push-notifications

I wan't to create me new application in expo react native with managed workflow. I have a paid apple developper account and all of my credentials are uploaded to my expo account. And builds for iOS and Android are working fine.
Specially my Apple Push Notification Service key has been uploaded to expo account too. But when I try to send a notification with the Expo Notification Tool my phone doesn't receive anything. But if I try to launch my application with Expo Go, it works.
So, in production mode, my notifications doesn't work.
But I successfully get my Expo Push token and my permissions to send notifications are okay.
I follow this documentation to setup my notifications : https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/
This is my code in my App.js :

```
    async registerForPushNotificationsAsync() {
        let token;
        if (Constants.isDevice) {
          const { status: existingStatus } = await Notifications.getPermissionsAsync();
          let finalStatus = existingStatus;
          if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
            const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
            finalStatus = status;
          }
          if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
            alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
            return;
          }
          token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;
          console.log(token);
        } else {
          alert('Must use physical device for Push Notifications');
        }
      
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
          Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
            name: 'default',
            importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
            vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
            lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
          });
        }
      
        return token;
      }
    
      _handleNotification = async notification => {
        console.log(notification);
        if (notification.remote) {
          Vibration.vibrate();                                                  
          const notificationId = Notifications.presentLocalNotificationAsync({      
            title: "Follow @technoplato",  
            body: "To learn yourself goodly (also follow PewDiePie)",                                             
            ios: { _displayInForeground: true }                                
          });                                                                       
        } 
        this.setState({ notification: notification });
      };
    
      _handleNotificationResponse = response => {
        console.log(response);
      };
    
      componentDidMount() {
        this.registerForPushNotificationsAsync().then(token => {
          this.setState({expoPushToken: token})
          alert('Push Token: ' + token);
        });
    
        Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(this._handleNotification);
        
             Notifications.addNotificationResponseReceivedListener(this._handleNotificationResponse);
      }
```

And this is my app.json :

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Spirit",
    "slug": "spirit-app",
    "version": "1.0.2",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": false,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.ml-dev.spirit.app"
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.ml.dev.spirit.app"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Do you have an idea that cause this issue ?

Comment: Are you using an ios simulator? I think you won't receive it on the ios simulator.

Comment: No it's on my physical device. iPhone 12 with iOS 14.7.1.

Comment: Did you try this tool? https://expo.dev/notifications for testing

Comment: It's exactly this tool that I used

Comment: having the same issue. It seems we cannot create ExpoPushTokens from the physical devices but they work fine when the app is loaded through ExpoGo app. This started happening sometime after June 22, 2021.

Comment: Finally, my code works in production mode, I just type the wrong exponent token. On the simulators applications like on macOS or in the AVD, you can't generate an exponent token, but on physical devices with expo go or with standalone apps the exponent token is generated successfully.

Comment: I use https://nativenotify.com/ for Expo managed workflow push notifications. I was able to get push notifications running in 15 minutes.